# Making some traffic hazard in Carla simulator

Tags: carla

In Carla simulator I can make some traffic using generate_traffic.py
But I want to make some cars or pedestrians ignoring traffic lights.
In this case what code should I change?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using any class derived from `BasicAgent (PythonAPI\carla\agents\navigation\basic_agent.py)` to control the generated actors, then you can pass `ignore_traffic_lights = True` to `opt_dict` constructor parameter.
Also, you can alter the following function of `BasicAgent` in order to customize the actors affected by traffic lights.

```
def _affected_by_traffic_light(self, lights_list=None, max_distance=None):
```